# Get current position of marker from clustering

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Hi I'm new to android and i have been working with google maps i have added marker to google maps like this

```
 options.position(point.lt);
  options.title(point.getName());         
 options.snippet(point.getAddress());
```

and adding tag while adding marker like this and by doing this i'm able to get the current marker position

```
mMap.addMarker(options).setTag(counter);
```

But now i'm doing same thing with **clustering** like this

```
mClusterManager.addItem(new MyItems(new LatLng(lat, lng),name,ad));
```

but i'm unable to set tag with it 
Can anybody please tell me how to do this or any other alternate thanks for your help

Comment: @Anony-Mousse will you please help me

Comment: No, I don't use Android. I only fixed your tags.